# How can Ansible Playbook add new records to MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ansible, addition, record, new-operator

I need to know if I can add new records to MS SQL Server DB as part of Ansible playbook.
We are trying to keep records in MSSQL Server of each deployment we have done, and it would be very convenient if it could be done directly from the playbook, since this will guarantee that for every host, when the deployment pass- it is updated directly

Comment: There is no `ansible` module to insert entries in a MS SQL Server DB, could probably use the `command` module calling `sqlcmd` to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- Using ansible [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module) module with `sqlcmd` tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017
- Implement you custom module in python with use of `pyodbc`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

  > There are several python SQL drivers available. However, Microsoft
  >   places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver

I am currently using first option with prepared statement in jinja on my ubuntu machine and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I finally decided to create a groovy script for the MS-SQL part and activate it from Ansible

Answer (score 0):

We have explain how to connect to MSSQL using same part of query. You have pass hostfile where your sql server hostname

**- name: sqltest Query
hc.sts:windows
gather_facts:no

```
  vars: 
     dbuser:"sysadmin"
     dbpass:"test@123" 
     
     tasks:
     -name :connectivity
      win_shell "GEt-Wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk"
      register:results
      ingore_errors:yes
      
    -debug: var=results
       ingore_errors=yes
       
    -name: dbststa
       win_command: sqlcmd -U {{dbuser}} -P {{dbpass}} -Q "select @@servername"
        register: query
        ingore_errors:yes
        
    -debug:var=Query
        ingore_errors:yes
 

    enter code here**
```